# Prettier точка с запятой в дженерике

Tags: prettier

Подскажите как в prittier избавиться от точки с запятой в дженерике

Хочу добиться вот такого результата, но по умолчанию он меняет запятую перед `wsId: string,` на точку с запятой

```
PayloadAction<{ wsId: string, value: ServersResponse[] }>
```